# How to process large files in NetLogo?

Tags: programming-languages

I am running into problems in NetLogo with large *.csv / *.txt files.

The documents can consist of about 1 million data sets and I need to read them (to eventually create a diagram based on the data).

With the most straightforward source code, my program needs about 2 minutes to process these files.

How should I approach reading such large data files faster in NetLogo?  Is NetLogo even suitable for such tasks (as it seems to be designed more for teaching and learning)?

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of your existing source code to the (edited) question?

Comment: Consider processing the files outside NetLogo and then create a summary file, then process the summary file in NetLogo.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to see where the hotspots are? Sometimes fairly simple changes (e.g., reading a batch of lines instead of reading them individually) can improve performance significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to extend NetLogo in Java, and take advantage of one of the highly optimised CSV readers or TXT parsers readily available. Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/.

If that doesn't do the trick, you might need to pre-process the data into something that can be read faster. Without knowing the data, it's hard to speculate what.